# How to collect headers from a json file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to change a json file to CSV. Here's my Json :

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "email": "colleengriffith@quintity.com",
    "tags": [
      "consectetur",
      "quis"
    ],
    "profiles": {
      "facebook": {
        "id": 0,
        "picture": "//fbcdn.com/a2244bc1-b10c-4d91-9ce8-184337c6b898.jpg"
      },
      "twitter": {
        "id": 0,
        "picture": "//twcdn.com/ad9e8cd3-3133-423e-8bbf-0602e4048c22.jpg"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "email": "maryellengriffin@ginkle.com",
    "tags": [
      "veniam",
      "elit",
      "mollit"
    ],
     "profiles": {
       "facebook": {
         "id": 1,
         "picture": "//fbcdn.com/12e070e0-21ea-4663-97d0-46bc9c7b67a4.jpg"
       },
       "twitter": {
         "id": 1,
         "picture": "//twcdn.com/3057792f-5dfb-4c4b-86b5-cce4d6bbf7ac.jpg"
       }
     }
   }
 ]
```

All I want first is to collect the headers. Here's what I tried :

```
json = JSON.parse(File.open("live.json").read)
headings = SortedSet.new
json.each do |hash|
  headings.merge(hash.values)
end
```

and It returns me `#<SortedSet:0x007fa592128088>`

Then, I tried to understand what happened (I did not by the way) but I saw that when I ask for my `json.values` I do not have the nested values. Here's what I have :

```
id
email
tags
profiles
```

Output expected is :

```
id, email, tags, profiles.facebook.id, profiles.facebook.picture, profiles.twitter.id, profiles.twitter.picture
```

So my question is, does anybody knows how to get those headers ? Is there a simple way to get them without using SortedSet ?

Many Thanks !

Comment: What exact output do you expect?

Comment: please mention your expected output.

Comment: There is no chance you get `id`, `email` etc by calling `hash.values`.

Comment: I edited it to show you the output i'm expecting to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get nested key using get_recursive_keys method

```
def get_recursive_keys(hash, nested_key=nil)
  hash.each_with_object([]) do |(k,v),keys|      
    k = "#{nested_key}.#{k}" unless nested_key.nil?
    if v.is_a? Hash
      keys.concat(get_recursive_keys(v, k))
    else
      keys << k
    end
  end
end
```

And then append in your sorted set like this:

```
json = JSON.parse(File.open("live.json").read)
headings = SortedSet.new
json.each do |hash|
  headings.merge(get_recursive_keys(hash))
end
```

Now headings of Keys:

```
#<SortedSet: {"email", "id", "profiles.facebook.id", "profiles.facebook.picture", "profiles.twitter.id", "profiles.twitter.picture", "tags"}>
```

Comment: I like the way you wrote your code. But I have one question about it. When I run your code, my heading variable equal `#<SortedSet:0x007fd22616b0c0>`
Any idea ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: @RaphaëlFOSSE Hey I am just using p headings instead of puts headings :)

Comment: Right ! haha However, `tags` did not appear into the output I have, neither on your as I can see.

Comment: Oops, didn't noticed, sorry. Thanks again!

Comment: You’re abusing `each` with an outer local variable, use `json.each_with_object(SortedSet.new) { |hash, set| set.merge(get_recursive_keys(hash)) }` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
json = <<-END
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "email": "colleengriffith@quintity.com",
    "tags": [
      "consectetur",
      "quis"
    ],
    "profiles": {
      "facebook": {
        "id": 0,
        "picture": "//fbcdn.com/a2244bc1-b10c-4d91-9ce8-184337c6b898.jpg"
      },
      "twitter": {
        "id": 0,
        "picture": "//twcdn.com/ad9e8cd3-3133-423e-8bbf-0602e4048c22.jpg"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "email": "maryellengriffin@ginkle.com",
    "tags": [
      "veniam",
      "elit",
      "mollit"
    ],
     "profiles": {
       "facebook": {
         "id": 1,
         "picture": "//fbcdn.com/12e070e0-21ea-4663-97d0-46bc9c7b67a4.jpg"
       },
       "twitter": {
         "id": 1,
         "picture": "//twcdn.com/3057792f-5dfb-4c4b-86b5-cce4d6bbf7ac.jpg"
       }
     }
   }
 ]
END

CSV.generate do |csv| 
  csv << [:id, :email, :tags, :profiles] # add headers with order
  JSON.parse(json).each do |item| 
    csv << [item['id'], item['email'], item['tags'].join(','), item['profiles']] # add rows with the same order
  end
end
```

It'll give you the following csv:

```
id,email,tags,profiles
0,colleengriffith@quintity.com,"consectetur,quis","{""facebook""=>{""id""=>0, ""picture""=>""//fbcdn.com/a2244bc1-b10c-4d91-9ce8-184337c6b898.jpg""}, ""twitter""=>{""id""=>0, ""picture""=>""//twcdn.com/ad9e8cd3-3133-423e-8bbf-0602e4048c22.jpg""}}"
1,maryellengriffin@ginkle.com,"veniam,elit,mollit","{""facebook""=>{""id""=>1, ""picture""=>""//fbcdn.com/12e070e0-21ea-4663-97d0-46bc9c7b67a4.jpg""}, ""twitter""=>{""id""=>1, ""picture""=>""//twcdn.com/3057792f-5dfb-4c4b-86b5-cce4d6bbf7ac.jpg""}}"
```

But you have to decide what to do with profiles.

**Updated**

```
CSV.generate do |csv| 
  csv << ['id', 'email', 'tags', 'profiles.facebook.id', 'profiles.facebook.picture', 'profiles.twitter.id', 'profiles.twitter.picture'] 
  JSON.parse(json).each do |item| 
    csv << [item['id'], item['email'], item['tags'].join(','), item['profiles']['facebook']['id'], item['profiles']['facebook']['picture'], item['profiles']['twitter']['id'], item['profiles']['twitter']['picture']] 
  end
end
```

will result

```
id,email,tags,profiles.facebook.id,profiles.facebook.picture,profiles.twitter.id,profiles.twitter.picture
0,colleengriffith@quintity.com,"consectetur,quis",0,//fbcdn.com/a2244bc1-b10c-4d91-9ce8-184337c6b898.jpg,0,//twcdn.com/ad9e8cd3-3133-423e-8bbf-0602e4048c22.jpg
1,maryellengriffin@ginkle.com,"veniam,elit,mollit",1,//fbcdn.com/12e070e0-21ea-4663-97d0-46bc9c7b67a4.jpg,1,//twcdn.com/3057792f-5dfb-4c4b-86b5-cce4d6bbf7ac.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've decided what I have to do with profiles and I need to collect them, same way than my output.

Answer (score 0):

For the hash of any nesting level:

```
get = ->(hash, prefix = nil) do
        hash.flat_map do |k, v|
          v.is_a?(Hash) ? get.(v, k) : [prefix, k].compact.join('.')
        end
      end

json.map(&get)
#⇒ array of titles in each hash
json.map(&get).first
#⇒ ["id", "email", "tags",
#   "facebook.id", "facebook.picture",
#   "twitter.id", "twitter.picture"]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the question, and It worked indeed. however, what you wrote is not that clear in my head... Could you explain me a bit more ?

Comment: I am not sure what could I add to make it more explicit. `get` lambda extracts the keys recursively and joins them with a dot.